# How can we implement pagecurl animation in tableview?

Tags: iphone

Ha ii every body ,how can we implement a page-curl in tableview,i have a tableview which contains pages of the book and i have implement the touch events in the tableview cell for next chapter and previous chapter,left-swipe for next and right-swipe for previous chapter,when we swipe the tableview it reloads the next chapter and previous chapter content,it really works well but i want it in a page-curl animation,when the user swipe left or right tableview loads content with a page-curl animation.Is that possible to do in a tableview cell?my code for left and right swipe for chapter navigation as follows.

```
-(void) handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {


     if(![delegate.selectedChapter isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[DbHandler mNumberOfChaptersInBook:delegate.selectedBook]]]) {

        // if the currentChapter is the last then do nothing
         delegate.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegate.selectedChapter intValue] + 1];
         [delegate reloadVerses];
         [self resetReadViewToVerse:1];
         [table removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }
    if (recognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ) {
        self.table.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
    else if(recognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        self.table.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }


    return;



}
-(void) handleSwipeGestureleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    if(![delegate.selectedChapter isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {

        delegate.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegate.selectedChapter intValue] - 1];
        [delegate reloadVerses];
        [self resetReadViewToVerse:1]; 
        [table removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }
    if (recognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ) {
        self.table.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
    else if(recognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        self.table.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }

    return;


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animCompleteHandler:finished:context:)];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

just put this code inside the methods.Thanks

Comment: hey thanks it helped me alot but can u suggest me something for right and left curl